# Solution for an Second Order Linear Differential Equation

Tags: calculus

I try to understand the math in a paper. In the paper, they are solving a second-order linear differential equation in the form of $$\ddot{\delta}(t)+ \lambda \delta(t) = 0 $$ where $\lambda$ is constant.

They are assuming that the general solution is to be in the following forms:
$$\delta(t) = De^{jwt} + \bar{D}e^{jwt}=Fcos(wt+\varphi)$$

where $\lambda=w^2$

How did they come up with the solution? I solved it with the standard approach, and my solution is $$\delta(t) = C_1e^{j \lambda t} + C_2e^{-j \lambda t}$$

Answer (score 1):

I assume $j$ to be the imaginary unit in your notation.

Deriving your solution, you get one factor $\lambda$ each time you derive via the chain rule. This would lead to $\ddot{\delta} = -\lambda^2 \delta$.
Thats why the solution starts with some $\omega$ which satisfies $\omega^2 = \lambda$.
If you modify this in your approach, you will get the same solution.

Comment: Please explain the part in more detail after the $\ddot{\delta} = -\lambda^2 \delta$. I don't know how to get to the solution. Do u know why they can say that the solution has a $D$ and $\bar{D}$, instead of two general variables? or is it just an assumption?

Comment: Sorry, I did not even notice that the two coefficients are complex conjugates. You are correct that the general solution has two independent coefficients. The additional constraints can only arise from other assumptions that are motivated for example by the physical situation this initial value problem is trying to describe.

Comment: In this case, the left and right summand are complex conjugates of one another. Their sum is a real valued function.

Answer (score 0):

To get from your solution to the given solution, we need to add one assumption: that $\delta(t)$ is a real-valued function.

With that assumption, we get the constraint $\mathrm{Im}(\delta(t)) = 0$, which we can then apply to get:

$$\begin{eqnarray} \mathrm{Im}(\delta(t)) & = & 0 \\
\mathrm{Im}(C_1 e^{j \lambda t} + C_2 e^{-j \lambda t}) & = & 0 \\
\mathrm{Im}(C_1(\cos \lambda t + j \sin \lambda t) + C_2(\cos \lambda t - j \sin \lambda t)) & = & 0
\end{eqnarray}$$

Setting $t = 0$ gives $\mathrm{Im}(C_1) + \mathrm{Im}(C_2) = 0$, while setting $t = \frac{\pi}{\lambda}$ gives $\mathrm{Re}(C_1) - \mathrm{Re}(C_2) = 0$, and if we choose $C_1 = D$ then those two equations tell us that $C_2 = \bar{D}$.